# How does this Matlab/Octave code create a Boolean matrix from a vector?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, octave, linear-algebra

The first line of code creates some vector with "discrete labels", and the second line of code creates a sparse matrix with ones at the index that the label represents. "eye" creates an identity matrix, but then even if the vector "a" is much longer, this effect of creating a sparse matrix still works!?

Could you please help me understand what is going on?

```
octave:4> a = [1 3 5 7 9 2 4 6 8 10]
a =

    1    3    5    7    9    2    4    6    8   10

octave:5> eye(10)(a,:)
ans =

Permutation Matrix

   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The notation `eye(10)(a,:)` in Octave means: build the size-`10` identity matrix (`eye(10)`) and then pick its rows in the order given by `a` (note that `a` is used as the first index, which corresponds to rows, and `:` as second index, which means "take all columns"). So, for example, the `4`th row of the result is row `7` of the identity matrix, because the `4`th entry of `a` contains `7`.

From this explanation it's clear that `a` can be as long as you want, provided that all its values are integers in the range `1`...`10` (these are the rows available in `eye(10)`).

Note that in Matlab this "chained" indexing is not allowed. You would have to first assign `eye(10)` to a variable, and then index into that variable:

```
m = eye(10);
m(a,:)
```

Lastly, a minor "technical" note: the obtained matrix is not of type `logical` (Matlab's Boolean data type), nor is it `sparse`. Rather, it's a `full` matrix of type `double`.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I like Octave.  I don't like the temporary variable stuff.  Either way, +1 :)

Comment: @rayryeng I've never used Octave, but it does seem to be very powerful notation. Also, I gather broadcasting is automatic: no need for `bsxfun`, right?!

Comment: Exactly :)... If any of the singleton dimensions are 1, then Octave will be able to handle broadcasting implicitly.  However, if this isn't the case, `bsxfun` is supported in Octave: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Broadcasting.html

Comment: @rayryeng Interesing link! I didn't know that the "broadcasting" name comes from Numpy, and that this operation is supported in so many languages

Comment: Yup! Numpy is great for MATLAB users. The syntax and mechanisms are so similar that within 20 minutes you can start using it right away. Sometimes I answer Numpy questions if I'm fast enough, but there are so many python followers that I simply don't get the chance!

Comment: @rayryeng Oh really? Maybe I should give it a chance. But I don't know Python; maybe I should learn it first?

Comment: You actually don't need to... Not at first. http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users. To get the basic environment going, you only need to follow that tutorial. If you do want to get into how the actual language works then yes most certainly learn it, but check that link out and let me know :)

Comment: @rayryeng I was precisely reading that! Certainly it looks easy coming from Matlab. But I guess at this moment I lack a reason to do the effort... Matlab serves all my needs. And that includes a program to randomly copy files to my mp3 player, or to make incremental backups of my hard-drive :-) What I definitely do want to get better at is Android and Java

Comment: In addition, I'll add that there's no "boolean" datatype in Matlab – it's called `logical`, and consists only of `true` (`1`) and `false` (`0`) values.

Comment: @LuisMendo Cool!  I've been meaning to take a look a `java.awt.Robot` in more detail.  You have some pretty nice answers that talk about it!

Comment: @horchler Oops. Yes, I meant `logical`. I will correct my answer

Comment: @rayryeng I don't know much about that class either. I took it from the post I linked in that answer :-)